# divisibility of integral part of a surd

Tags: divisibility

Given that "$n$" belongs to prime numbers and is greater than 2
; $(a,b)$ belongs to integers and $0<\sqrt{a}-b<1$

> $(\sqrt{a}+b)^n=N+f$ where $f \in (0,1)$

Show that $N$-$2b^n$ is divisible by $2abn$

Comment: $a = 2, \, b = 1,\, n = 2$: $(\sqrt{2}-1)^2 = 3+2\sqrt{2} = 5 + 2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. $5 - 2b^2 = 3$ is not divisible by $2abn = 8$.

Comment: Duh, that should have been a $+$, $(\sqrt{2}+1)^2 = 3+2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $ n $ is odd when $ n > 2 $, $ N = (\sqrt{a}+b)^n - (\sqrt{a}-b)^n $. Expanding it we can get:
$$ C_{n}^{2k} (\sqrt{a})^{2k}(b)^{n-2k} - C_{n}^{2k} (\sqrt{a})^{2k}(-b)^{n-2k} = 2C_{n}^{2k} (a)^{2k}(b)^{n-2k} $$
$$ C_{n}^{2k-1} (\sqrt{a})^{2k-1}(b)^{n-2k+1} - C_{n}^{2k-1} (\sqrt{a})^{2k-1}(-b)^{n-2k+1} = 0 $$

Comment: @ easymath3 There's a jump from step 2 to 3,can you explain it?By the way,when n is not a prime number,just an odd then N-2b^n would not always be divisible by n

Comment: @Tom Lynd YES, you must prove that $ n | C_{n}^{2k} $, when n is prime it's obvious.

Comment: Thanks,how come I overlooked it<<